# HMVC Codeigniter: Unable to locate the specified class: Session.php

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am trying to set up hmvc in codeigniter 3.1.3 using https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/downloads. I have autoloaded my session library `$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');` However when I create `MY_Controller` that extends `MX_Controller` I get an error

> Unable to locate the specified class: Session.php

This is `MY_Controller.php`

```
 <?php
class MY_Controller extends MX_Controller {

  function __construct() {

    parent::__construct();
  }
}
```

Comment: So did you get the same message when you tried to load the session directly in your MY_Controller.php constructor? i.e $this->load->library('session');

Comment: @TimBrownlaw yes I did that. The error is gone but I dont understand why the autoload throws up errors

Answer (score 1):

i found a simple solution. when you extends MX_Controller in MY_Controller then you will used MY_Controller everywhere

Example:

```
class Welcome extends MY_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
}
```